# Is the length of the proof of propositional tautology a PA-total function?

Tags: logic, proof-theory

Suppose we have fix some interpretation of propositional (not first-order!) logic inside PA, and say $f(n) = $ {the maximum length of a proof of a tautology with $n$ propositional primitives}

Questions:

1) Is this PA-definable? I think so, because all of the deduction rules of propositional logic are codeable as PA relations.

2) Does PA prove that this function is total a priori? We know there is some sort of exponential bound (convert everything into CNF, and then inspect the result), but can we prove that this function is PA-computable without knowing there exists a bound necessarily?

Motivation: I want to bound the length of proofs of tautologies of length $n$. While one can do this by considering carefully the proof of Completeness for propositional logic, this is quite tedious, and I was wondering whether we can justifiably bound this function by, say, the Goodstein function (or some other similarly fast-growing function).

Comment: Your definition of $f$ is not very clear: I think yhou mean $f(n)$ is the maximum over all tautologies $\phi$ of length $n$ of the shortest proof of $\phi$.

Comment: @RobArthan: Thanks - edited the original post now.

Comment: It's an indictment to the state of the [tag:proof-theory] tag that I'm excited whenever I see a question that uses it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $PA$ can prove that the "propositional busy beaver" is total. In fact, the bound you cite is provable in $PA$ - the standard proof doesn't use anything beyond $PA$!